# What implications would a solution of the *Standard Conjectures* have on the *Hodge Conjecture*?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, motives, hodge-theory, algebraic-cycles

I'm new to the field, so I just would like to know what implications would have a solution of the *Standard Conjectures* on the *Hodge Conjecture*. I read somewhere they are related in some way, but I don't know anything else.

Comment: I thought the implication goes the other way: the Hodge conjecture implies some of the standard conjectures.

Comment: See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_conjectures_on_algebraic_cycles). The Hodge conjecture implies that numerical equivalence coincides with homological equivalence ("conjecture D"), which in turn implies the  Lefschetz-type conjecture ("conjecture B").

Comment: @PiotrAchinger Upto my knowledge, it _is_ the other way around. I have never heard of the standard conjectures implying the standard conjectures, and [neither has Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Standard+Conjectures&oq=Standard+Conjectures&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1149j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=standard+conjectures+hodge+conjecture).

Comment: @PiotrAchinger Oh, wait! "_[sic]_ The Lefschetz standard conjecture for varieties which are fibered in
Abelian varieties over a smooth curve also implies the Hodge conjecture for Abelian varieties
as shown by Yves Andre in Y. Andre _Pour une theorie inconditionnelle des motifs_, Inst. Hautes  Etudes Sci.
Publ. Math. (1996), no. 83, p. 5-49." (http://www.math.u-psud.fr/~fcharles/Lef_cmh_3.pdf).

Comment: The Hodge conjecture implies all the Grothendieck's standard conjectures over base fields of characteristic 0.

Answer (score 6):

Answered in the comments by Sanath Devalapurkar:

> [sic] The Lefschetz standard conjecture for varieties which are fibered in Abelian varieties over a smooth curve also implies the Hodge conjecture for Abelian varieties as shown by Yves Andre in Y. Andre Pour une theorie inconditionnelle des motifs, Inst. Hautes Etudes Sci. Publ. Math. (1996), no. 83, p. 5-49. ([math.u-psud.fr/~fcharles/Lef_cmh_3.pdf](http://math.u-psud.fr/~fcharles/Lef_cmh_3.pdf)).

---

Also note M. Carmona's comment:

> The Hodge conjecture implies all the Grothendieck's standard conjectures over base fields of characteristic 0

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers: If the standard conjectures in characteristic 0 are true, then the category of motives by André is equivalent to the category of numerical motives. This means that motivated cycles are algebraic. This means that the variational Hodge conjecture implies the Hodge conjecture. (For the analogous statement for motivated cycles is proven by André.)